# Create a flag column based on condition pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
ID      Price      Duration
1       100        60
2       200        2
3       1          366
4       1          365
```

I would like to create a flag column based on condition in Price column and Duration column.

Steps:

If Price is less than 20 flag it as False else flag it as True

If Duration is less than 30 flag it as False else flag it as True

Expected Output:

```
ID      Price      Duration     Price_Flag      Duration_Flag
1       100        60           True            True
2       200        2            True            False
3       1          366          False           True
4       10         365          False           True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea is compare by list by order of columns name `['Price','Duration']` by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html):

```
df[['Price_Flag','Duration_Flag']] = df[['Price','Duration']].gt([20,30])
```

Or use [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for each column separately:

```
df['Price_Flag'] = df['Price'].gt(20)
df['Duration_Flag'] = df['Duration'].gt(30)
```

Or use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.assign(Price_Flag = df['Price'].gt(20),
               Duration_Flag = df['Duration'].gt(30))
```

---

```
print (df)
   ID  Price  Duration  Price_Flag  Duration_Flag
0   1    100        60        True           True
1   2    200         2        True          False
2   3      1       366       False           True
3   4      1       365       False           True
```